# What are some ways to interact with a jar post creation in the command line?

Tags: java

I want to create a system where there is a central processor that works on tasks. Tasks would be sent to the central processor at random, in both amount and time sent.

e.g.

- Central Processor start
- Task 0 comes at time 0
- Task 1 comes at time 1
- Task 2 comes at time 6
- Task 3 comes at time 6
- Task 4 comes at time 10
- Central Processor is still running at time 11

The user will decide when to launch a task for the processor to work on. The flow would be something like this. Processor starts up. A task is received and processor works on the task. If any task is received when the processor is busy, add it to a queue.

A task would be to run through automated tasks, taking in file location, device name, device type. My first thought was to have the Central Processor be a jar and have the task creation interact with the jar post java -jar CentralProcessor.jar but I don't think this is possible.

Ideally a task would be sent through command line to the jar (After the jar has been started) from any command line, e.g. a second one - not the one that started the jar. The Java program would be a command line program. How would I go about doing this? I've learned one option is to have use HTTP but that seems bulky.

Comment: And what would be the common environment between all these tasks? If you ask this question it means that such existing mechanisms such as, for instance, cron, don't suit you. Why don't they?

Comment: So you want a processor running as a Daemon.  It would need to receive tasks in some way.  Using command line as you suggest would be problematic since the `java -jar whatever.jar` creates a new process and jvm.  What you're really looking for is a client-server model, which suggest socket interactions.  Your `CentralProcessor` is the server, and you'd need a client jar such that `java -jar Client.jar -some -args -describing -task` would connect to the Central Processor and submit the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

So you want a processor running as a Daemon. It would need to receive tasks in some way. Using command line as you suggest would be problematic since the java -jar whatever.jar creates a new process and jvm. What you're really looking for is a client-server model, which suggest socket interactions. Your CentralProcessor is the server, and you'd need a client jar such that java -jar Client.jar -some -args -describing -task would connect to the Central Processor and submit the task. – Taylor